# How to convert random number generation from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, random

Here is the code I am trying to convert from Matlab:

```
function x=finiterv(s,p,m)
% returns m samples
% of finite (s,p) rv
%s=s(:);p=p(:);
r=rand(m,1);
cdf=cumsum(p);
x=s(1+count(cdf,r));`
```

And here is my Python code:

```
def infinterv(s,p,m):
#return m samples
#of finite (s,p) rv
r=random.uniform((m,1))
cdf=p.cumsum(axis=0)
x=s(1+count(cdf,))`
```

I get an error saying

```
uniform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

I think I am not converting the random uniform function correctly!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `r=random.uniform(m,1)`?

Comment: Which `random` is this? Is it from NumPy? Please include your import statements so we know what is going on. Also copy-paste the full error message including the stack trace. Don’t paraphrase error messages!

Answer (score 0):

Change `r=random.uniform((m,1))` to `r=random.uniform(m,1)`.

The way you wrote it, you are passing one argument (which is a tuple) to the `uniform` function, but it expects two individual numbers.